# Linux command to merge grep and ls -lrt output

Tags: linux, grep, command, ls

I have a set of log files in a folder and sub folders.
I want to show the number of occurrence  of a specific log along with the file time stamp.
I am simplifying commands here to search only under one folder for solution purpose.

`grep` command can give me number of occurrences or filenames, but not the timestamps. If I pipe it with `ls` command, then I loose the number of occurrences. If I pipe `ls` output to grep, I loose the timestamps.

Below are sample commands. I need the number of occurrences from first command after the second command filenames.

```
----/logs/server> grep -c 'sample search text' *  | grep -v :0
i0_server2_wls.log:980
i0_server2_wls.log00005:20
i0_server1_wls.log:4
i0_server1_wls.log00023:186
i0_server1_wls.log00024:767
i0_server1_wls.log00027:49
i0_server1_wls.log00028:401
i0_server1_wls.log00029:199
i0_server1_wls.log00031:8122
i0_server1_wls.log00033:7744
i0_server1_wls.log00034:18476


----/logs/server> grep -l 'sample search text' * | xargs ls -lrt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser  41824670 Jul  8 20:42 i0_server1_wls.log00023
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser  71726325 Jul 19 20:45 i0_server1_wls.log00024
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser  91704808 Aug 22 17:47 i0_server1_wls.log00027
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser  56183363 Aug 29 18:33 i0_server1_wls.log00028
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser 162665267 Sep  6 20:14 i0_server1_wls.log00029
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser  80384219 Sep 28 22:03 i0_server2_wls.log00005
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser 170614866 Nov 19 22:35 i0_server1_wls.log00031
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser 142315429 Dec  8 20:48 i0_server1_wls.log00033
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser 335498557 Dec 12 22:38 i0_server1_wls.log00034
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser  62375653 Dec 13 19:23 i0_server2_wls.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mygroup myuser  38069112 Dec 13 19:23 i0_server1_wls.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the paste command you can combine the outputs line by line like this:

```
grep -c 'sample search text' * | grep -v :0 > file1.txt
grep -l 'sample search text' * | xargs ls -lrt > file2.txt
paste -d" " file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The crux here's that `ls -lrt` can reorder the files, so a simple `paste` with the counts in the order returned from `grep` can yield a mixup. Besides it may be preferable to run `grep` only once. `gawk` comes in handy to achieve the needed result.

```
grep -c 'sample search text' * | gawk -F: '
    { if ($2) count[$1] = $2 }  # collect all names with non-zero counts
END { command = "xargs ls -lrt" # process to pass the file names through
      for (name in count) print name |& command
      close(command, "to")      # we are done writing "to" the coprocess
      FS=" "; while (command |& getline) print $0 "\t" count[$9]
    }'
```

This makes use of the `gawk` extension for [Two-Way Communications with Another Process](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html).